# Uploading audio files with PHP

Tags: php, file-upload

I need to make a website that will allow registered users to upload audio files.
I wonder is there any bullet proof practice regarding security.
The site is built in PHP

Comment: What kind of security are you concerned about? Limiting file access, preventing the upload of illegal content, DRM, etc?

Answer (score 2):

Check mime type of uploading file

```
mp3 -> audio/mpeg
```

More here: http://www.w3schools.com/media/media_mimeref.asp

Answer (score 2):

You will want to check the file type carefully.  This means **not** just doing a substring on the file name to get the extension.  The extension is not a concrete indicator of what the file actually is.

As Danzan said, you will want to check the MIME type of the file, using some code like this:

```
if ($_FILES["audioUpload"]["type"] == "audio/mpeg") {
//proceed with upload procedure
} else {
echo "Only mp3's are allowed to be uploaded.";
}
```

This reduces the chances of a user uploading, say, malicious PHP code into your upload directory to basically zero.

Answer (score 1):

Bullet-proof file type check is provided via combination of getimagesize, fileinfo extension and mime_content_type function ([Nette Framework](http://api.nette.org/2.0/source-Utils.MimeTypeDetector.php.html#41) property):

```
// $file is absolute path to the uploaded file
$info = @getimagesize($file); // @ - files smaller than 12 bytes causes read error
if (isset($info['mime'])) {
   return $info['mime'];
} elseif (extension_loaded('fileinfo')) {
   $type = preg_replace('#[\s;].*$#', '', finfo_file(finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME), $file));
} elseif (function_exists('mime_content_type')) {
   $type = mime_content_type($file);
}
return isset($type) && preg_match('#^\S+/\S+$#', $type)
    ? $type 
    : 'application/octet-stream';
```

You can not trust any data coming from the client, because they can be easily forged.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking about user submitted data.
I have already file extension check as well as mime type, but still not sure if that's all needed to prevent malicious code injected on server

Comment: I think the server is secure in this case (you cannot run audio file as a PHP script), but the unavoidable problem will still be that users could upload an audio file with contained malicious code in case some vulnerability is discovered (that could be dangerous for users that download this file from your server). But I don't think you have to worry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload anything with PHP. Here's an example: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php

Regarding security, you have to verify that only certain people are allowed to upload stuff and that you verify the contents of what they're uploading (file size, file type, etc).